# Stackdriver monitoring nosuchmethoderror when having a 'google-api-services-compute'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

There is an error from a java application using the Stackdriver Monitoring client when I have a dependency to the google-api-services-compute.

exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.validateName(Metadata.java:629)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:637)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:567)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:742)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:737)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:593)
        at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:589)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.<init>(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:60)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:220)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:193)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:185)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:155)
        at com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.stub.GrpcMetricServiceStub.create(GrpcMetricServiceStub.java:176)
        at com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.stub.MetricServiceStubSettings.createStub(MetricServiceStubSettings.java:188)
        at com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.MetricServiceClient.<init>(MetricServiceClient.java:157)
        at com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.MetricServiceClient.create(MetricServiceClient.java:138)
        at com.google.cloud.monitoring.v3.MetricServiceClient.create(MetricServiceClient.java:129)
        at com.vmware.adapter3.gcp.builder.GoogleCloudMonitoringManager.testGoogleCloudMonitoringConnection(GoogleCloudMonitoringManager.java:356)
```

on the create method:
        MetricServiceClient metricServiceClient = MetricServiceClient.create();

only when Maven Dependencies :

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
     <version>${project.gson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
  <version>${project.http.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
  <version>${project.oauth.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-compute</artifactId>
  <version>v1-rev158-1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
  <version>v1-rev158-1.25.0</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>google-cloud-monitoring</artifactId>
      <version>1.98.0</version>
```

Please help me to come out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is the lower case function name "create": It has to start with a higher case "C", being "Create", as in "[MetricServiceClient.Create()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Monitoring.V3/api/Google.Cloud.Monitoring.V3.MetricServiceClient.html#Google_Cloud_Monitoring_V3_MetricServiceClient_Create_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_ServiceEndpoint_Google_Cloud_Monitoring_V3_MetricServiceSettings_)".

Comment: not seeting upper case Create method in MEtricServiceClient. try  (MetricServiceClient mServiceClient = MetricServiceClient.create()) {

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean. Can you try setting the first letter of the function to upper case and executing the code?

Comment: using 1.98 googles-cloud-monitoring jar, there are three create methods (All are small case create() method) to Constructs an instance of MetricServiceClient with default or given setting. like                                        
            final MetricServiceClient client = MetricServiceClient.create();

Comment: Could you try using the newest version, which is 1.99, and tell me if it works?

Comment: Thanks @asbovelw, I have tried with newer version of (1.99) as suggested above, it didn't work. solved this problem, this is due to the guava jar conflict issue. main process(root) is staring from another app. As per the maven, the library’s version whose node is nearest to the root (another app) in the dependency tree will be used. In this case, guava 18.0 is getting the call from GCP monitoring client library